# Reusbale React Toastify Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

A react-toast component creadted with an intention to publish it as an private npm pacakge. It can usedul for many internal projects.

So, below is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-toastify-toast-with-react-component-forked-mu2l9c?file=/src/App.js:297-484

However there are two problems encountered

1. on Click of buttons, two toast box are being displayed
2. Passing down of Ref to child components.

Again, the code uses, `ref`,  `current.showToast`. So it sounds bad to pass down `refs` to child Components.

What I want to achieve is DECLARE ONE TIME and USE ANYWHERE.

So, in the parent Component

```
import {ToastSuccess, ToastSuccessMeta, ToastError, ToastErrorMeta } from 'custom-library'

return(
<>
   <ToastSuccess />
   <ToastError />
</>
)
```

In Child components

```
 <button  onClick={() => ToastSuccessMeta.showToast({ position: "top-right", message: "Custom Success Toast" })}>Show Toast </button>
 <button  onClick={() => ToastErrorMeta.showToast({ position: "top-right", message: "Custom Error Toast" })}>Show Toast Erro</button>
```

I don't know if I can achieve this. Please note that `custom-library` is the place where Toast-Container will be configured. . And projects will install and import it to use the toast.

Your help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-toastify showing multiple toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62578112/react-toastify-showing-multiple-toast)

Comment: I asked two question. 1 is solved, while the other is how NOT to use REF. .

Comment: can you please check my answer, I hope this will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I recommended you, instead of making a multiple toast components you can make a common component as you can see the below code and you can use this component anywhere in your app.

```
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

export default (options) => {
  const toastOptions = {
    position: options.position,
    autoClose: 3000,
    hideProgressBar: false,
    closeOnClick: true,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    draggable: true,
    progress: undefined,
    theme: "colored"
  };

  switch (options.type) {
    case "info":
      toast.info(options.message, toastOptions);
      break;
    case "success":
      toast.success(options.message, toastOptions);
      break;
    case "error":
      toast.error(options.message, toastOptions);
      break;
    case "warning":
      toast.warning(options.message, toastOptions);
      break;
    default:
      toast.error("Something went wrong", toastOptions);
  }
};
```